# Getting “Cannot call a class as a function” in my React Project :throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");

Tags: reactjs

I'm making COVID-19 tracker project and I got this error and I'm stuck, not sure where its coming from.

````
import { Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import cx from 'react-countup';
import styles from './Cards.module.css';

const CardComponent = ({ className, cardTitle, value, lastUpdate, cardSubtitle }) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={3} component={Card} className={cx(styles.card, className)}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          {cardTitle}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
          <CountUp start={0} end={value} duration={2.75} separator="," />
        </Typography>
        <Typography color="textSecondary">
          {new Date(lastUpdate).toDateString()}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          {cardSubtitle}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Grid>
  );

const Info = ({ data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate } }) => {
  if (!confirmed) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="h2">Global</Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
        <CardComponent
          className={styles.infected}
          cardTitle="Infected"
          value={confirmed.value}
          lastUpdate={lastUpdate}
          cardSubtitle="Number of active cases from COVID-19."
        />
        <CardComponent
          className={styles.recovered}
          cardTitle="Recovered"
          value={recovered.value}
          lastUpdate={lastUpdate}
          cardSubtitle="Number of recoveries from COVID-19."
        />
        <CardComponent
          className={styles.deaths}
          cardTitle="Deaths"
          value={deaths.value}
          lastUpdate={lastUpdate}
          cardSubtitle="Number of deaths caused by COVID-19."
        />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a JSX element in your component but a simple string.

```js
if (!confirmed) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
```